# JDBC to MySQL via NetBeans in Java Web Application

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to establish a connection with the database ( MySQL) in this servlet in the `doPost()` method. I have no idea where the problem is. Can I establish the connection within this servlet or do I need to make a new Java class?

```
package com.EventListing.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ViewEventListing extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    } 

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String eventTitle= request.getParameter("eventTitle");
        String location = request.getParameter("location");

        out.println("Welcome "+ eventTitle+"! The Email Address "+location+" has been "
                  + "added to our mailing list.");


         try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             out.println("Driver Loading Done!");
         } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/eventlistings" ;
         String user = "root";
         String pass = "sheridan";


            Connection conn ;;
        try {
             conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(connURL, user, pass);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ViewEventListing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        out.println("Connection Done!");


        String sql = "INSERT INTO eventlistings "+"(Title, Location)" + 
    "VALUES('simran', 'Brampton');";


          PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement();

          out.close();
    }

    /** 
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

This is the servlet using which I want to fetch some data from MySQL but I could not even connect to the database. Where I am trying to use the Prepared Statement that is, preparedStatement ps, I get an error.

Comment: please post your error message.

Comment: It Says " no suitable method found for prepared Statement(no argments "

Comment: this is not the servlet problem. you need to set sql arguments when create preparestatment. I think you miss the usage of preparement. please try to understand this link for example of preparement. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/preparestatement-object-example.htm

Comment: have you inclueded mysql-connector-jar in your project???

Comment: i suggest you to refer tutorial given on this link http://www.journaldev.com/1997/servlet-example-in-java-with-database-connection-and-log4j-integration  this might help you solve your problem...i think you are missing something while providing db connectivity to your web app...

Answer (score 1):

1. Only use a **PreparedStatment**  where you want to reuse the sql with different arguments
2. Suggest instead you use

   Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

   stmt.execute(sql);

instead of:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement();
```